# Calculate the derivative of $Γ(z,v)$ with respect to $z$

Tags: derivatives, gamma-function

Let $Γ(z,v)=∫_{v}^{+∞}t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$ be the incomplete $Γ$-function. My **question** is: Calculate the derivative of $Γ(z,v)$ with respect to $z$.

Comment: So what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: See [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) under derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption would be

$\frac{d}{dz}\Gamma(z,t)=\int_v^\infty\ln(t)t^{z-1}e^{-t}\,dt$